# Something is wrong with my Linux OS system and still i can't figure it out - GPU Related /nVidia/Hardware Utilization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, nvidia, intel-graphics

## Hello Unix&Linux,

*reading time ( estimate ) : 3 m, 9 s |*

**The Question/hitches are about the : GPU/Utilization |**

scroll down for specs |

**A back story :**

*i installed linux mint 20.01 a while a go - and i enjoyed using it for the most part , great Distro for the beginners*

**what's wrong then ? :**

*after a while "`using mint 20.01`" i noticed **high CPU usages** - the ram seems to be reasonable*

mostly the high CPU usage starts when i

- open a browser

and

- scroll down
  a web page mostly a article or news sites
  the CPU usage starts to spike upto **50%+** then it sits at 30%

ohh , don't make me start on the browser **Video encode/decoding Utilization**

**i tried to test it with other programs like blender** - still the CPU utilization feels not right , and it slower -- rendering -- moving around the canvas -- Hover Animations has a noticeable delay on it

## on windows 10

- the browser uses less CPU for browsing
- blender **feels okay** for the most part - when i render the sense - moving around the canvas

***I know Linux & windows are totally diffract Systems/OS/Kernels** - but i think handling hardware shouldn't matter that much on what OS you use they both should utilize my hardware correctly*

the Distro or the Flavor doesn't matter for the most part * At least in my case

**what i mean by that is** i tried other distros to see if the CPU spikes might be fixed or i could get a better performance out of it

***unfortunately not*** - i tried ->

**Debian** : *Ubuntu (Kubuntu , Xubuntu , Ubuntu Mate ) , Mint-(ubuntu) , Pop!_OS ^nVida drivers 460*

**Arch** : *Manjaro*

**OS Currently using :** `im using (Arch)Manjaro`

**things I've done to try a solve the issue :**

i did a bit of research on this topic and i found out wiki arch post about browser hardware acceleration / || enable / setting up video encoding decoding - it did show that every thing is running fine but still didn't fix CPU Utilization issue - spiking the CPU

wiki arch instructed me to enable some futures on `about:config` on `firefox` it did say it's `enabled` but `htop/glances` says nothing has change in case of the still High CPU Usage - so i tried to install `google chrome` - `on chrome://CPU` most of the settings are `truned off ( on linux )` so i went to `chrome://flags` and tired to enabled them it did indeed shows as enabled in `chrome://GPU` but with no effect at all - i think the issue isn't in the browser it self there's something else , please correct me if I'm wrong

some articles says i should add `graphic card ppa & update` - that didn't work either - i know it's not recommended to do it but i though it might install new patches new version to fix my issue something , but no..

just to let you know that all this time the GPU - graphics card driver is installed 460 NVidia from the driver manger

there was a bug on `Linux mint 20.01` that when it switched to lower performance mode Nvidia control panel disappear and luckily there's a fix for that on linux mint community if i found the link i will put it here
[ [Link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=341289) ]

*on Nvidia control panel* - i tired all the modes '**low performance**' '**on demand**' '**high performance**' - they all the same in terms of performance or CPU utilization

**quick note : i use HTOP , Glances - to monitor CPU - RAM utilization**

```
i know HTOP : shows 1 core percentage and that dose not mean if that core running on 50% doesn't mean the over all CPU is 50%

i have 4 core - each core load is 40% 40% 40% 40% = 39 - 40% over all = htop

Glances tool : shows you the overall CPU utilization
```

so have you experienced something like that ? and if you did managed to fix it please let me know

or if you might know what the main case is - i'd love to hear your thoughts on it

---

Hardware Specs :

Using ENVY laptop ( notebook )

CPU : I7-6500U @ 2.50GHz

GPU : Nvidia Gefpre GTX 950M

IGPU : intel HD graphics 520

MEMORY : 16 GB

Linux located on a HDD drive with a capacity of 500GB

*-- something missing ? --*

please let me know in the comments

Comment: -> https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Have to guess what the question is. Is it that your CPU usage **consistently** too high - or is it just a bit of a blip?  I'm also guessing that you have loaded the nvidia proprietary drivers? Please edit your question so that it covers a single problem, but feel free to raise a second question as I'm not sure that the GPU stuff is relevant to a possible CPU problem.

Comment: @jeremy-boden `Is it that your CPU usage consistently too high` -- no only when the browser is running , `I'm also guessing that you have loaded the nvidia proprietary drivers? ` -- yes

Comment: I will create another post with full details (: , thanks for letting me know

Comment: In my experience (with a low-end nvidia card), the various GPU performance options make absolutely zero difference.

Comment: What happens to your CPU frequencies when you see a load of 40% and not much happening? I'd take note of any CPU temperature sensor readings.

Comment: `the various GPU performance options make` --  are you talking about drivers or performance tweaks ? -- `What happens to your CPU frequencies when you see a load of 40%`  CPU frequencies goes around 2.40 - 2.72 GHz at 40% -- `I'd take note of any CPU temperature sensor readings` I'll start take notes as you suggested about the CPU temps  -- thanks (: